# SOLR 4.10 plugin error SolrException Error handling reload action

Tags: java, solr

I have written a SOLR(4.10.3) plugin using netbeans. I have created jar by building the project.

My class name is SolrPostFilter (SolrPostFilter.jar file)
This is the complete path of this jar `~/solr-4.10/plugin/lib`. plugin jar file lies in lib directory.

I have registered my plugin like this in solrconfig.xml

```
<queryParser name="ModuloPostFilter" class="SolrPostFilter"/>
```

Is this path correct ?

When I reload core, following error appears

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error handling 'reload' action
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleReloadAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:737)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:225)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to reload core [collection1]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.reload(CoreContainer.java:591)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleReloadAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:735)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'SolrPostFilter'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:881)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.reload(SolrCore.java:437)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'SolrPostFilter'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:490)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:421)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SolrPostFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Where is the problem. I think, its path is not set. How to do it?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SolrPostFilter` check whether you have the required jar

Comment: yes, I have but I think, Its path is not correct, how to set that path. I have no idea about it